# coversational AI chatbot using langchain and chatgpt 3.5?

Tags: nlp, language-model, chatbot, llm

can we develop end to end hotel booking coversational AI chatbot using langchain and chatgpt 3.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

If you want your chatbot to actually book rooms, you can use the [OpenAI plugins feature](https://platform.openai.com/docs/plugins/introduction), which enables your chatbot to call APIs to perform actions.

You can use [langchain](https://www.langchain.com/) if you want, but it is not needed for that. Instead, you may simply use the OpenAI API through its [Python and Javascript wrappers](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference).

Comment: Could the downvoter please describe why this answer got their downvote? An explanation is customary and helpful for the community.